# How object files with templates are linked together

Tags: c++, templates, linker

Imagine we have three `.h` files:

`f.h`:

```
template <typename T> class Class {public: Class() {} T id(T x) { return x; }};
```

`g.h`:

```
template <typename T> class Class {public: Class() {} T id(T x) { return x + 100; }};
```

`h.h`:

```
template <typename T> class Class {public: Class(); T id(T x); };
```

Now, we also have three `.cpp` files:

`f.cpp`:

```
#include "f.h"
int f(int x) { Class<int> t; return t.id(x); }
```

`g.cpp`:

```
#include "g.h"
int g(int x) { Class<int> t; return t.id(x);  }
```

`h.cpp`:

```
#include "h.h"
int h(int x) { Class<int> t; return t.id(x); }
```

Compiling them gives us `f.o`, `g.o` and `h.o`. Now let's throw in this `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio>

extern int f(int);
extern int g(int);
extern int h(int);

int main() {
   std::cout << f(1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << g(2) << std::endl;
   std::cout << h(3) << std::endl;
}
```

A-a-and let's do `g++ main.cpp f.o g.o h.o`. Now comes my actual surprise: Since those three `.o` files contain three different definitions for `int Class<int>::id(int)`, I expect to get a linking error. However, what I get is a working `a.out`, which prints `1 2 3`. And if I reorder `.o` files in the command, it will print `101 102 103`.

And now for the actual questions: How exactly does the linker perform linking in this case? How does it figures out what instantiation of `Class<int>` to keep and what to throw away? And why it does not complain about multiple definitions?

`nm` utility gives following output for `nm f.o g.o h.o`:

```
f.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text
00000000 t .text$_ZN5ClassIiE2idEi
00000000 t .text$_ZN5ClassIiEC1Ev
00000000 T __Z1fi
00000000 T __ZN5ClassIiE2idEi
00000000 T __ZN5ClassIiEC1Ev

g.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 t .text
00000000 t .text$_ZN5ClassIiE2idEi
00000000 t .text$_ZN5ClassIiEC1Ev
00000000 T __Z1gi
00000000 T __ZN5ClassIiE2idEi
00000000 T __ZN5ClassIiEC1Ev

h.o:
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 d .eh_frame
00000000 t .text
00000000 T __Z1hi
         U __ZN5ClassIiE2idEi
         U __ZN5ClassIiEC1Ev
```

Clearly, `f.o` and `g.o` both export symbol `__ZN5ClassIiE2idEi`, and `h.o` imports this symbol (capital letters mean external linkage). And it leads to no errors. Why?

Comment: Did you try `nm` or `objdump` on the .o files to get the information?

Comment: I sense an ODR violation...

Comment: @harper: `f.o`, `g.o` and `h.o` has symbols with exactly same names.

Comment: @KErrek SB: That's the whole point of this example. But I always thought that ODR violation inevitably leads to linker errors.

Comment: @Joker_vD I tried it in MSVC 2008 and had the same behavior. And another thing: add `public:` to your Class or make it `struct`

Comment: It does give link errors in some cases and on some compilers.  This is a major pain with the STL on Visual studio 2008 and having some libraries that use _SECURE_SCL=0 and some that don't.  It all compiles fine but will randomly crash due to the ODR violation.  After complaining to Microsoft they mentioned that they were considering adding #pragma odr to detect stuff like this.  Not sure where they got with that and additionally not sure if GCC has anything similar.

Comment: You will get multiply defined symbols for free functions.

Comment: An ODR violation leads to *undiagnosable, undiagnosed, undefined* behaviour...

Answer (score 3):

This problem is actually well known: You're violating the ODR. Due to the nature of templates the compiler and linker don't notice that. What happens is the following:

The linker *assumes* that the ODR has NOT been violated and is therefor free to use ANY of the instantiations of the template (aka. all instantiations of the template with the same parameters lead to the exact same code being generated). This system makes sense in as long as you don't violate the ODR.

Now in your case the linker chooses to use the first instantiation it gets, which leads to the result being dependent on the order of linking.

Comment: Actually he's _not_ violating it, he's using it well :)

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense: if I declared plain functions, I *would* get linking errors. And more than that, ODR is C++ language concept, and linkers don't know *anything* about languages. They just link object files together.

Comment: Templates != normal functions. The definition of templates is always present in EVERY translation unit (unless you have something like export at hand^^). The linker then throws away all but one (which one is obviously implementation defined) definition (to fulfill ODR...) as they are assumed to be the same (ODR).

Comment: @xtofl: Each translation unit has a different definition of `Class`. That violated the ODR.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Function templates (and member functions of class templates) follow the rules of inline functions: they are allowed to be defined in multiple translation units, as long as all definitions are identical (and no diagnosis is required).

Comment: @MFH: By this logic, I could have named functions in `f.cpp`, `g.cpp` and `h.cpp` just `f`, and still wouldn't have linking errors: `f` is defined in every translation unit, and the linker would just throw all but one away, but I know for sure it is wrong.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Only if they are inline. Diagnosis *is* required for multiply-defined non-inline functions with external linkage, but not for inline functions (including templates).

Comment: @Mike: Okay, I am now at my machine, and I checked object files: `Classes<int>::id(int)` has external linkage (capital letters `T` and `U`).

Comment: @Joker_vD: Yes, but it's a template, so it follows the rules of inline functions. Therefore, you are allowed multiple identical definitions, and no diagnosis is required if you erroneously provide non-identical definitions.

Comment: @Mike: But how the *linker* knows about those rules? Linkers are language-unaware, right? And if I change `int h(int x)` to `int f(int x)` in `h.cpp`, I have `T __Z1fi` instead of `T __Z1hi` in `h.o`, and it *does* raise a linking error. Maybe I don't see some additional info about symbols?

Comment: @Joker_vD: It doesn't have to know the rules! It sees: Symbol XYZ is undefined. On linking the first object file/library that defines the symbol it maps the symbol to the corresponding address. The symbol is than removed from the table with undefined symbols => second definition is not interesting to the linker in any way (you can actually test that quite a bit on Unix by messing with the order of linking libraries... If you link to a library in Unix whose symbols aren't currently in the undefined symbol table the linker will simply not use any symbols of the lib... => order is important!)

Comment: @MFH: Some time ago, when I was studying, I was taught, among other things, this: when linker adds an OBJ gile to the module, it goes through the list of its exported symbols: if a symbol from OBJ is not in the module, add it to the module and mark it as resolved; if it is in the module and marked as unresolved, mark it as resolved; and if it's in the module and marked as resolved — linking error. That's classical stuff. But apparently something has changed, and I want to learn *what*.

Comment: @Joker_vD: I doubt that was ever correct in every case. **BTW:** §14.7.5: `For a given template and a given set of template-arguments,
— an explicit instantiation definition shall appear at most once in a program,
— an explicit specialization shall be defined at most once in a program (according to 3.2), and
— both an explicit instantiation and a declaration of an explicit specialization shall not appear in a
program unless the explicit instantiation follows a declaration of the explicit specialization.
An implementation is not required to diagnose a violation of this rule.` 3.2 == ODR

Comment: @Joker_vD: In order to link C++ objects, the linker does indeed need to know these rules and allow certain symbols to be multiply defined; otherwise, it couldn't form part of a conformant C++ implementation. What you were taught is sufficient for a basic linker for C and similar languages, but not quite sufficient for C++.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds too obvious, but your class is using implicit inlining. That is, when ever you put the source code inside the class declaration, you are "hinting" that you want it inlined.
So...

The only things the linker will see are f(),g() and h().

It might be interesting to retry your code with something like this, although it is still so simple, the compiler might simply inline it still (depending on your compiler).

```
template <typename T> class Class 
{
public: 
     Class() {}
T id(T x);
};

template <typename T> 
T Class::id(T x)
{ 
   return x; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not so: `h.o` has no definition of `Class<int>.id(int)`, so the linker must import it from somewhere (see the question; I've added list of symbols, `T` means "external linkage, has actual code", `U` means "external linkage, but has no code and has to be imported").